# Как скрыть выпадающий список Spinner`a при клике?

Tags: java, android

Необходимо сделать `Spinner`, по клику на который должен появляться новый `layout`, содержащий список. По клику на элемент списка происходит возврат значения на предыдущий `layout` и он проставляется в `Spinner`.

Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> yourSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, someStrings) {

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                parent);

        convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = convertView.getLayoutParams();
        p.height = 0; // set the height
        convertView.setLayoutParams(p);

        return convertView;
    }
};
spinner.setAdapter(yourSpinnerAdapter);
```

но ничего не выходит и список все равно видно. В принципе, мне будет достаточно просто скрыть выпадающий список.
Если в коде выше изменить строку

```
convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

на

```
convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

то выпадающий список остается без текста (т.е. появляется просто прямоугольник).

PS Spinner при этом должен быть кликабельным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ваших условий не необходимости использовать спиннер.
Для того, чтобы у виджета был вид спиннера, вовсе не обязательно использовать именно его. Для вашей задачи вполне подойдет обычный `TextView` с бэкграундом спиннера - внешне он будет выглядеть, как спинер, будет кликабелен и из него ничего не будет выпадать при клике

Comment: Не подходит т.к. есть необходимость отлавливать клик по спиннеру) Как сказали - так и делаю)

Comment: @user3239600 Кто сказал так делать? Задавайте вопрос максимально точно - нужно, чтобы спиннер принимал клики, но список не разворачивался. Из вашего вопроса, как он есть не очень то понятно, что вам на самом деле надо.

Comment: Так необходимо сделать согласно дизайну за несоответствие которому кхм. Там должен быть spinner, по клику на который должен появляться новый layout, содержащий список. По клику на элемент списка происходит возврат значения на предыдущий layout и он проставляется в spinner.

Comment: @user3239600 По вашим условиям непонятно, зачем использовать спиннер.Для того, чтобы у виджета был вид спиннера, вовсе не обязательно использовать менно его. Для вашей задачи вполне подойдет обычный `TextView` с бэкграундом спиннера - внешне он будет выглядеть, как спинер, будет кликабелен и из него ничего не будет выпадать при клике.

Comment: но при клике на него будет вылазить клавиатура и оно будет редактируемо вручную.
Да, можно после получения данных сделать его enabled(false), но клавиатура скорее всего останется (как и выпадающий список спиннера). Так что шило на мыло получается.

Comment: с чего для `TextView` будет появляться клавиатура? - виджеты текствью не предполагают редактирования пользователем, не надо путать с `EditText`

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо.